# Debezium Kafka connector mongodb

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Is there any way to specify to kafka connector which actions on mongo should consider. Actually, I don't want that kafka does anything when a mongo document is deleted (just update and insert new doc should be considered).
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can write a SMT (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-66%3A+Single+Message+Transforms+for+Kafka+Connect) that can filter out unwanted operations. An example is of dropping a `delete` record is en excerpt from this SMT - https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/blob/master/outbox/event-routing-smt/src/main/java/io/debezium/examples/outbox/routingsmt/EventRouter.java#L44